# How to fill a shape with two colors with a varying ratio using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill a TikZ shape/node with two colors that are spitted horizontally and be able to adjust the ratio between them like as follows (similar to a loading bar):

[image: TikZ color shade]

I tried to modify [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343674/227362) that uses shading but the rendering is different and always produces some color mixing:

[image: color shading example]

Comment: have a look athe answer below

Comment: is there something else required -- would you like to accept the answer

Comment: is there something else required -- would you like to accept the answer

Comment: @jsbibra This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadings,shapes.symbols, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={draw, cloud, cloud ignores aspect, }]
         \node[my node] (a1)  {Text};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[fill fraction/.style n args={2}{path picture={
            \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle
            ($(path picture bounding box.north west)!#2!(path picture bounding box.north east)$);}}]
        
    \draw (4, 0) node[cloud, cloud ignores aspect,draw,fill=blue, fill fraction={green}{0.7}] {Some
        other text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

The long text spoils the shape of the cloud so an edit

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadings,shapes.symbols, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={draw, cloud, cloud ignores aspect, }]
         \node[my node] (a1)  {Text};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[fill fraction/.style n args={2}{path picture={
            \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle
            ($(path picture bounding box.north west)!#2!(path picture bounding box.north east)$);}}]
        
    \draw (4, 0) node[cloud, cloud ignores aspect,draw,fill=blue, fill fraction={green}{0.7}] {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]