# How to avoid color gradient in table cell that is split in 2 colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, color, nicematrix

I adapted a solution from post [Multi-colored cell background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348933/multi-colored-cell-background) using Overleaf.

The code I use is the following:

```
%%% This code comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348933/multi-colored-cell-background with minor adjustments regarding the format of the table %%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    double color fill/.code 2 args={
        \pgfdeclareverticalshading[%
            tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom%
        ]{diagonalfill}{100bp}{%
            color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
            color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)
        }
        \tikzset{shade, left color=#1, right color=#2, shading=diagonalfill}
    }
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{%
  diagonal fill/.style 2 args={%
      double color fill={#1}{#2},
      shading angle=45,
      opacity=0.8},
  other filling/.style={%
      shade,
      shading=myshade, % myshade is defined below
      shading angle=0,
      opacity=0}
 }
    
    \noindent\begin{NiceTabular}{| p{0.25\textwidth}
            |p{0.02\textwidth}*{3}{|p{0.02\textwidth}}
            |p{0.02\textwidth}*{3}{|p{0.02\textwidth}}
            |p{0.02\textwidth}*{3}{|p{0.02\textwidth}}
            |p{0.02\textwidth}*{3}{|p{0.02\textwidth}}
            |}
                \hline 
                \textbf{Lorem}  
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{dolor}
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{sit} 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{amet} 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{beneficae} \\ \cline{2-17}
            \hline
            \hline
            \textbf{ipsum} &  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} \\
            \hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & \Block[tikz={diagonal fill={yellow}{green}}]{}{} & \Block[tikz={diagonal fill={yellow}{green}}]{}{} & &  \\
            \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

producing this result:
[image]

In contrast to the original post, the two colors are not strictly separated, but they have a gradient, even though I am very sure I am using the same code. I'd like to get rid of this gradient, can anyone help me with that ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I can confirm that this is the result on overleaf but not on an updated MikTeX system. Overleaf doesn't use the most updated system and sometimes you get unexpected results. I cannot say what's the outdated package that provoques these result.

Comment: In Overleaf, you have a setting called "PDF Viewer" (in the "Menu") : you can choice between "Overleaf" and "Browser". With "Overleaf", you have a good synchronisation between the LaTeX source and the view of the PDF. However, you may have some problems as yours. You can try to switch to the choice "Browser".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but switching to "Browser" sadly didn't do anything for me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe also try this approach (taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343392/47927)) which does not use the `shadings` library and hence should be displayed correctly on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  diagonal fill/.style 2 args={%
    fill=#2, path picture={
        \fill[#1, sharp corners] 
            (path picture bounding box.south west) -|
            (path picture bounding box.north east) -- cycle;
        }
    },
 }
    
    \noindent\begin{NiceTabular}{| p{0.25\textwidth}
            |p{0.02\textwidth}*{3}{|p{0.02\textwidth}}
            |p{0.02\textwidth}*{3}{|p{0.02\textwidth}}
            |p{0.02\textwidth}*{3}{|p{0.02\textwidth}}
            |p{0.02\textwidth}*{3}{|p{0.02\textwidth}}
            |}
                \hline 
                \textbf{Lorem}  
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{dolor}
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{sit} 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{amet} 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{beneficae} \\ \cline{2-17}
            \hline
            \hline
            \textbf{ipsum} &  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} \\
            \hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & \Block[tikz={diagonal fill={yellow}{green}}]{}{} & \Block[tikz={diagonal fill={yellow}{green}}]{}{} & &  \\
            \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Addendum**

In case you need to adjust the angle, you can use an enhanced version of the above approach that takes an angle as third argument (I used a simpler example to show the application, but you can as well apply this to the above code):

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{%
  diagonal fill/.style n args={3}{%
    fill=#2, path picture={
      \fill[#1, rotate=#3] 
        let \p1 = ($(path picture bounding box.south west)-(path picture bounding box.north east)$) 
        in (path picture bounding box.center) -- ++(0,{veclen(\x1,\y1)}) arc (90:-90:{veclen(\x1,\y1)}) -- cycle;
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[diagonal fill={red}{blue}{30}] (0,0) rectangle ++(5,5);

\fill[diagonal fill={gray}{cyan}{-10}] (7.5,2.5) ellipse (2 and 3);

\fill[diagonal fill={yellow}{green}{135}] (10,1) rectangle ++(6,3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]