# Tikz gives white node background on macOS but colours as it is supposed to on Linux with custome shading

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a weird issue with Tikz in particular because my document compiles as it is supposed to on Linux but not on macOS.
The Tikz image I am trying to make is this:

[image]

Which is what is created on Linux, however on macOS the nodes have a white background, and I simply cannot figure out why.

The code below (minimal working example), is all the code involved when generating the image.
On Linux I use the newest latex in the fedora package repository and on macOS I use the newest MacTex.
Any ideas why this is happening?

```latex
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\tikzset{
    double color fill/.code 2 args={
        \pgfdeclareverticalshading[%
            tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom%
        ]{diagonalfill}{100bp}{%
            color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
            color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)
        }
        \tikzset{shade, left color=#1, right color=#2, shading=diagonalfill}
    }
  }

\tikzstyle{node-base}=[circle, draw, align=center, font=\footnotesize, minimum size=1.3cm]
\tikzstyle{dc-node}=[node-base, double color fill={AntiqueWhite}{LightBlue}, shading angle=45]
\tikzstyle{label}=[align=center]

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[dc-node] (n1) at (0, 0) {N$_1$};
    \node[dc-node] (n2) at (2.5, -.5) {N$_2$};
    \node[dc-node] (n3) at (2.5, -2.5) {N$_3$};
    \node[dc-node] (n4) at (0, -3) {N$_4$};
    \node[dc-node] (n5) at (-2.5, -2.5) {N$_5$};
    \node[dc-node] (n6) at (-2.5, -.5) {N$_6$};
    \node[label, rotate=-20] (lbl) at (-1.25, -3) {$\cdots$};

    \draw (n1) to[bend right=4] (n2);
    \draw (n1) to[bend right=4] (n3);
    \draw (n1) to[bend left=4] (n6);
    \draw (n1) to[bend left=4] (n5);
    \draw (n1) -- (n4);

    \draw (n2) to[bend left=4] (n3);
    \draw (n2) to[bend left=10] (n4);
    \draw (n2) to[bend left=10] (n5);
    \draw (n2.north) to[bend right=35] (n6.north);

    \draw (n3) to[bend right=4] (n4);
    \draw (n3.south) to[bend left=35] (n5.south);
    \draw (n3) to[bend left=10] (n6);

    \draw (n4) to[bend right=4] (n5);
    \draw (n4) to[bend left=10] (n6);

    \draw (n5) to[bend left=4] (n6); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: unlikely to be operating system related (unless you mean the same pdf if copied from one system to the other renders differently) more likely to be a difference in the tex systems, add `\listfiles` and compare the file lists on the two systems for version differences

Comment: The output looks as expected both in the free Adobe Acrobat Reader and in the TeXstudio built-in pdf viewer, which is poppler based. I'm on macOS 11.5.2 with latest texlive 2021.

Comment: I am also on MacOS using TeXLive 2021 (but has not been updated in some time), and am seeing the same output that you describe (with a white background).  Once you installed MacTex, did you update the packages? That needs to be done as MacTeX release is frozen sometime around April.  One soltuion I found is using the `diagonal fill` style from [TikZ: Rectangle with diagonal fill (two colors)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343392/4301) instead of `double color fill` does work.

Comment: @PeterGrill Interesting that is actually the TexExchange post I took inspiration from :D and thanks and yes I updated after installing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will try that later today when I am in front of my Mac thank you

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ huh interesting. I will take a look and see if I can get it to working on my Mac

Comment: More info is welcome, eg your latex2e version, tikz version, the engine you used, and maybe even a screenshot of the "white background" effect.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is right. The output in Acrobat Reader looks as per your post but with TeXShop the nodes have the white background. TeXShop uses _almost_ the same pdfkit as Preview so both have issues. This seems to be a bug with Apple's pdfkit.

Comment: Interesting @PeterGrill and David Carlisle I will file a bug report with Apple then, when I have confirmed it later in the day that I experience the same :)

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX code works as it is supposed to.

What is not working is Apple Preview, as identified by David Carlisle and Peter Grill.
The only solution I have found is to use an alternative PDF viewer.

I have filed a bug report with Apple.