Shading young tableau
EDIT: Following Jasper Habicht's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/732655/308324 ,
This code works well for all cells (you may need to fine tune the varuiables, which is annoying but doable)
\newcommand{\shadehalf}[3]{%
    \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=1, scale=0.8] 
            % Hardcoded coordinates
            \def\leng{0.65}    % Rectangle side length
            \def\xone{0}    % Rectangle x1
            \def\yone{-0.16}   % Rectangle y1
            % Use \pgfmathsetmacro for calculating \xtwo and \ytwo
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwo}{\xone + \leng}    % Rectangle x2
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwo}{\yone + \leng}    % Rectangle y2
            % Draw the shapes
            \fill[#1] (\xone,\yone) rectangle (\xtwo,\ytwo); % Full square with first color
            \fill[#2] (\xone,\yone) -- (\xtwo,\yone) -- (\xtwo,\ytwo) -- cycle; % Half-shading triangle
            % Centered text
            \node at ({(\xtwo+\xone)/2},{(\yone+\ytwo)*0.6}) {#3};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
}


I am struggling to make a diagonal shading in Young tableaux. For example in the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For \scalebox
\begin{document}
\begin{ytableau}
    % line 1
    *(green) 1 & *(red) 1& *(green) 1 \\
    % line 2
   \none& *(green) 1 & *(red) 1\\
    % line 3
    \none & \none & *(green) 1 
\end{ytableau}
\end{document}

which produces

I want to have diagonal shading in each boxes as in 1. TikZ: Rectangle with diagonal fill (two colors)
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadings,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{
    double color fill/.code 2 args={
        \pgfdeclareverticalshading[%
            tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom%
        ]{diagonalfill}{100bp}{%
            color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
            color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)
        }
        \tikzset{shade, left color=#1, right color=#2, shading=diagonalfill}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={ double color fill={green}{blue}}]
\node[my node, shading angle=45]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I think Staircase paths through young tableaux  should be helpful but I fail to do what I want.
I will appreciate any help. Thank you

Welcome to TeX.SX!

how about this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611179/140722

Not thouroughly tested and might break for certain cell contents:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_new:Npn \shadehalf(#1,#2)#3& {
    \draw_begin:
        \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
        \draw_transform_shift:n { -0.5*\macro@boxdim@YT , -5pt }
        \draw_scope_begin:
            \color_select:n {#1}
            \draw_path_moveto:n { 0 , 0 }
            \draw_path_lineto:n { 0 , \macro@boxdim@YT }
            \draw_path_lineto:n { \macro@boxdim@YT , \macro@boxdim@YT }
            \draw_path_lineto:n { \macro@boxdim@YT , 0 }
            \draw_path_close:
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
            \color_select:n {#2}
            \draw_path_moveto:n { 0 , 0 }
            \draw_path_lineto:n { \macro@boxdim@YT , \macro@boxdim@YT }
            \draw_path_lineto:n { \macro@boxdim@YT , 0 }
            \draw_path_close:
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
        \draw_scope_end:
    \draw_end:
    \hbox_overlap_center:n {#3} &
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{ytableau}
    % line 1
    \shadehalf(green,blue) 1 & *(red) 1 & *(green) 1 \\
    % line 2
    \none & *(green) 1 & *(red) 1\\
    % line 3
    \none & \none & *(green) 1 
\end{ytableau}
\end{document}



Such a nice suggestion

With nicematrix and this post Multi-colored cell background
% \documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/732605/shading-young-tableau
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \usetikzlibrary{
  % shadows,
  % shadings,
  % shapes.symbols
  % }
  \tikzset{%
    double color fill/.code 2 args={
        \pgfdeclareverticalshading[%
            tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom%
        ]{diagonalfill}{100bp}{%
            color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
            color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)
        }
        \tikzset{shade, left color=#1, right color=#2, shading=diagonalfill}
    }
}
\begin{document}

\pgfset
{
  nicematrix/cell-node/.append style =
  { 
    minimum width=1.5em,
    minimum height=1.5em, 
  }
}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[
  hvlines,
  cell-space-limits=3pt,
  corners=SW,
]
\CodeBefore
\chessboardcolors[opacity=0.1]{green}{red}
\Body
% In this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348933/multi-colored-cell-background/610185#610185
\Block[tikz={double color fill={red}{blue}, shading angle=45, opacity=0.5}]{}{1}&1&1\\
&1&1\\
&&1
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}



Such a nice suggestion
